# Update query identifier

Tags: sql, oracle

```
UPDATE Table1 a
SET a.Col2 = (
    SELECT SubStr(Trim(b.Col2),-10,10)
    FROM Table2 b
    WHERE (InStr(SubStr(Trim(b.Col2),-5,5),'/')=1 
        AND InStr(SubStr(Trim(b.Col2),1,(Length(Trim(b.Col2))-10)),'/')=0 
        AND SubStr(b.Col1,1,2)='01'
        AND b.Col3 != 000103))
WHERE SubStr(b.Col1,-8,8)=SubStr(a.Col1,1,8)
    AND a.Col3 = 1;
```

Error at Command Line:9 Column:14
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00904: "B"."Col1": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"

Line 9 is `WHERE SubStr(b.Col1,-8,8)=SubStr(a.Col1,1,8)`

Comment: You're referencing the inner query in the outer. Don't, move this condition into the inner query.

Comment: the subquery you use in SET a.birthdate = (...) cannot have any outer reference to it.

Comment: How do I join the two tables if I can not reference it?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to [MERGE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/statements_9016.htm#SQLRF01606):

```
MERGE INTO Table1 a
USING (
    SELECT *
    FROM Table2 b
    WHERE (InStr(SubStr(Trim(b.Col2),-5,5),'/')=1 
        AND InStr(SubStr(Trim(b.Col2),1,(Length(Trim(b.Col2))-10)),'/')=0 
        AND SubStr(b.Col1,1,2)='01'
        AND b.Col3 != 000103)
) c ON (SubStr(c.Col1,-8,8)=SubStr(a.Col1,1,8))
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET a.Col2 = SubStr(Trim(c.Col2),-10,10)
        WHERE a.Col3 = 1;
```